# Dynamically displaying JSON data in browser with node.js without refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, node.js

I have this simple node.js server that grabs JSON data from an external source and then displays it in a browser window. How can I make it update every minute (when the JSON is updated) automatically on the page without a refresh?

Tangent: is there a better way to request and parse the JSON? I'm currently using a module that simulates XMLHttpRequest, which is not included in the node core.

```
var http = require("http");
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){

    function rqr(x,y){
            x.open('GET', y, false);
            x.send(null);
            if(x.status == 0)
            dump(x.responseText);
    }

    var req1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var address = 'http://dogecoinaverage.com/USD.json'
    rqr(req1,address);

    var json = req1.responseText,
    obj = JSON.parse(json);

    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    res.end(obj.vwap);

});     

server.listen(8003);
console.log("ok");
```

Comment: Seems like there's lot of stuff you need to understand if you are asking this question. Search for tutorials about ajax and real time web apps

Answer (score 0):

With [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) your server can emit some events to client, like make the client refresh the JSON.